# Repository tab is missing in Organizer window - Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I updated my xcode from version 4 to 5 and I have couple projects on Github.
The interest thing is when I open organizer window, the repository tab is missing, can any one tell me where it goes?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

Apple is always mucking with menus and controls and UI between Xcode versions.

For Xcode 5, the current state of things is this: For every project you have open in Xcode that has a "`.svn`" or "`.git`" directory associated with it, you'll have access to the "Source Control" menu (which comes between "Debug" and "Window" in the main menu bar).

If you have multiple git projects that the project refers to, you should see all the repos that your project refers to (or has sub projects pointing to).

2)

And if you look under the "Accounts" tab in your Xcode preferences, you may find where the master list of all repositories (that Xcode knows about) is living.  On my machine it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I found it and imported my projects, thank you!